# placing text into title tag w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I think it is possible, just can't seem to be able to find how to do it. I need to pass a value into a title of a span with jQuery...

I already pass the width to it:

```
$("#mySpan").width(myWidth);

<span id="mySpan" title=""></span>
```

Comment: wow.. how fast answers come here.. was just typing and saw 2 other answers getting populated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#myspan').attr('title', 'sometitle');`

Comment: All three answers are similar, but @jackbot beat all by 1 min. :)

Answer (score 1):

`$("#mySpan").attr('title', 'some value');`

or

`document.getElementById('mySpan').title = 'some value';`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

```
$("#mySpan").attr("title", "yourValueHere");
```

This should work.